# How to start remote desktop service in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, remote-desktop

I'm only able to remotely connect to my Ubuntu box after it's logged in using VNC Viewer on my Windows box.

How do I setup ubuntu so that it starts the remote desktop service at boot up?

Comment: What are you trying to do remotely? Would ssh serve your purposes just as well?

Answer (score 1):

Just click on the Windows button then search for Desktop Sharing.

Enable it from there.

Comment: I did that to enable Desktop Sharing but it only starts when I'm logged in. I should have clarified that I plan on using this ubuntu box as a server and it won't be directly connected to a physical keyboard and mouse. Therefore, I won't be able to conveniently login into my ubuntu box when I reboot it.